# How do I mass-convert the "last modified" dates in a particular directory?

Tags: files, timestamps

For example, say, I know that my time-offsets are off by several hours (perhaps because my system clock was a few hours ahead at a certain time). In that case, how would I mass-change the "last modified" dates of all the files in a particular directory?

Note that different files will need to have their modification time changed to different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to apply a relative offset to the modification time of a file, you can do it with a combination of `touch(1)` and `stat(1)`. touch supports relative times, but they are relative to now, not the current time on a file. Instead you can use stat to get the current modification time and apply an offset.

For example, to apply a -2 hour offset to the modification time of a file:

```
touch -m -d @$(( $(stat -c %Y file.txt) - 7200 )) file.txt
```

`stat -c %Y file.txt` gets the modification time of `file.txt` as seconds since the epoch. Using bash *arithmetic expansion*, you can perform calculations, which in this case is to subtract 7200 seconds (2 hours). Using touch with `-m` to change the modification time and `-d` to specify a date, you can set the modification time to what was calculated. The `@` is a time format specifier that says the given time is in seconds since the epoch.

If you put this into a shell script, you can call it from `find` or `xargs` letting you use find to select the files you want to change.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file ; do
    touch -m -d @$(( $(stat -c %Y "$file") - 7200 )) "$file"
done
```

That will apply the change to the modification time of all files passed as arguments.

Comment: Does `for file` without an `in` clause imply `in "$*"`?

Comment: @killermist: Almost. An absent `in` clause means `in "$@"` - i.e. it iterates over the positional parameters.

Comment: Ah.  That is the variable I was looking for.  I'm not great at remembering bash's expansion variables.  Having more reason to forget them is indirectly encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

Modify one file by hand to the right time (using `touch ... TEMPLATE`).

Then change the rest by referencing that file (using `touch -r TEMPLATE TARGET`).

Comment: This sets all files to the date of that one file, which is not what the question asked.

Comment: @Gilles it is not clear if setting a unique time is not enough to solve this "problem". If the target is just not to have any files in the future - very fast - this solution is probably better than wasting many operations per file. This is just another solution for a mass time-change.

Comment: “perhaps because my system clock was a few hours ahead at a certain time”. Your solution does not work (and cannot be easily modified to work) in the example use case that was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
touch -m -r file.txt -d '-1 hour' file.txt
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing with this command and why.